# Extract Substrings using importxml in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Using IMPORTXML in google sheets. I want to extract part of the result into one cell.

```
=IMPORTXML(B1,"//div[@class='orca-rating SwtJyda color-yellow tbody-6']/span")
```

I got the result spread over several columns. B8:F8
[image: result spread to B8:F8]

The inspect element is like this. I only want the value "2". It is in cell B8.
[image: inspect element]

I think this can be done using substring-after. But I could not get the correct result.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is included in your expected direction, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following samples?

```
=REGEXREPLACE(JOIN("",IMPORTXML(B1,"//div[@class='orca-rating SwtJyda color-yellow tbody-6']/span")),"[^0-9]","")
```

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(JOIN("",IMPORTXML(B1,"//div[@class='orca-rating SwtJyda color-yellow tbody-6']/span")),"\((.*)\)")
```

#### References:

- [REGEXREPLACE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)
- [REGEXEXTRACT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244)

Answer (score 1):

I use this formula. That works too.

```
=INDEX(  IMPORTXML(B1,"//div[@class='orca-rating SwtJyda color-yellow tbody-6']/span"),3)
```

But tanaike's formula is very good.

Comment: thanks for the INDEX example. I could retrieve all values instead of just the 1st one adapted like so:
`=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(IMPORTXML("https://www.forexfactory.com/calendar?month=jul.2023","//td[@class='calendar__cell calendar__impact impact calendar__impact calendar__impact--low']//span/@title"),"Impact Expected",""))`